# Is there a specific gauntlet to test home-brewed character classes?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, class, playtesting

Recently I've been trying to play test [my custom character class](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?370729-Will-bound-Magus-WIP) by running it through a dungeon I developed and ran for a party last year. The class focuses around the idea of collecting monster abilities and spending points to modify your own body with them. The dungeon is largely nature and animal based and I have included a druid and fighter in the play test party for comparison.

This is just a dungeon I made up though, and probably isn't perfect for testing all and every home-brewed class. **Are there existing formats for a series of encounters at various levels with which home brewers may play test custom classes?**

Answer (score 10):

There is no formalized series of encounters by which you can test home brewed content at that time. There may be something established on a per forum basis on Enworld or WOTC's home brew section, however WOTC has not put anything out.

Additionally, officially published adventures are relatively thin. You could try grabbing some of the harder encounters/days out of the Tyranny of Dragons or Princes of the Apocalypse story lines, but that's going to be rudimentary at best and neither of those series go all the way to L20.

There are also two important sources published since I originally wrote this answer. The first is the DMG, which contains advice for building homebrew classes (see page 287-289), and also [published today](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/modifying-classes) is a guide to building new class options or tweaking existing classes. While this does not directly provide guidelines on how to create a home brew class, it provides great insight into the design intent of each class that has been officially published.

Comment: Ok thanks, my primary system of choice is Pathfinder so I might convert the class over into that once I have foundations. I will look into Enworld